# Translating a nested quantifier to plain English

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

> Let Q(x,y) denote "x + y = 0". What are the truth values of the
>   quantifications ∃y∀xQ(x,y) and ∀x∃yQ(x,y), where the domain for all
>   variables consists of all real numbers?

So from this problem, I take it to mean that ∃y∀xQ(x,y) translates to "There is a real number y such that for every real number x, x + y = 0." In other words, if you were to pick y = π, the statement says that every real number x + π = 0. So 1 + π should equal to 0. Obviously, this is false so the statement is false.

∀x∃yQ(x,y) means "For every real number x there exists a real number y such that x + y = 0." That means if you pick a single real number x, there is a single y such that x + y = 0. This is true.

Am I understanding this correctly?

And to further check that I am translating this correctly, here is another problem.

> Let Q(x,y,z) be the statement "x + y = z". What are the truth values
>   of the statements ∀x∀y∃zQ(x,y,z) and ∃z∀x∀yQ(x,y,z), where the domain
>   of all variables consists of all real numbers?

∀x∀y∃zQ(x,y,z) means that "For all real numbers x and all real numbers y, there exists a real number z such that x + y = z." That means whichever x and y you pick, you will get a unique number z, which is true.

∃z∀x∀yQ(x,y,z) means that "There exists a real number z such that for all real numbers x and all real numbers y it is true that x + y = z". This means if you were to pick z = 50 for example, the statement asserts that no matter which x and y you pick, added together you should get 50. So according to the statement, 1 + 2 should equal 50? Which is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of $\exists$ is not quite right, at least not in your reasoning. If you pick an element, say $x$, and the rest of the statement is false you cannot conclude that the whole statement is false. You may not have picked the right $x$. If, on the other hand, the rest of the statement is true the whole statement is true, because you found a $x$. (Also: $\exists$ makes no statement about uniqueness).

Consider $\exists y \forall x\colon (x - x = y)$. In your reasoning you could pick $y = 2$ and then $x - x = 2$ is false. But the statement is not false because there still exists an $y$ with the asked property (namely $y = 0$).

To argue that $\exists y \forall x Q(x,y)$ is false, where $Q(x,y)$ denotes $x+y=0$ you should prove that the negation of the statement is true, which is $\forall y \exists x \neg Q(x,y)$. So let $y \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary. You have to consider two cases: If $y = 0$ choose $x=1$, otherwise $x = 0$. In both cases $x+y\neq0$. (Note that the order of the quantifiers is important in the reasoning: You could choose $x$ depending on $x$ because it's $\forall y \exists x$, you could not do that with $\exists x \forall y$.)

Comment: I see.. So in the above examples, can you write out why each statement is true? I'm still rather lost.

Comment: So going back to ∃z∀x∀yQ(x,y,z), this statement is false because there exists no value of z such that x + y = z for all values of x and y.

Comment: You paraphrased the statement correctly, but you should try to find a reasoning similar to the one in my reply why the statement is false exactly. The argument I gave in my original reply was a bit too sloppy if you're just learning about logic, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: No you're awesome for helping. I am just learning logic so this is all pretty new and foreign feeling. I think I had a light bulb moment. ∃y∀xQ(x,y) is false because regardless of which y is picked, there will only be one x such that x + y = 0, not all real numbers x as the statement says. Yes?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. (And you reasoned that $\exists y \exists x Q(x,y)$ is a true statement.)